# Multiple solutions of partial fractions decomposition

Tags: partial-fractions

I'm learning about series, and there this bit about partial fractions decomposition that I want to ask.

[image]

Am I right to assume that, there are multiple way to achieve the form $\frac{A}{1 - \alpha_1x}+\frac{B}{1 - \alpha_2x}$, i.e. there might be several solutions to $(1 - \alpha_1x)(1 - \alpha_2x) = 1 - 3x +x^2$, and hence to $A$ and $B$, but we choose the one most suited to simplify $H(x)$?

If this is true, is there some observation that can make choosing the right set of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,A,B$ easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is not true. The partial fraction decomposition of any rational function is unique up to term order, as proven (for example) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518190/357390), so there will always be only one possible solution for the parameters involved, again up to term order.

Comment: I've just realized that the "different solutions" I got were in fact the same, but expressed in different forms (though clearly some form is better suited to deduce $h_n$ than other). But thanks for the recommended reading!